# Android Market - replace apk without notifying/forcing users to update

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, notify

I realeased a new version 2.2 of my app just few days ago. Then I found few minor bugs and would like to upload fixed version to the Market. But these bugs are not critical and I don't want to annoy those users who have already downloaded version 2.2 with notification about new version.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't. If the bugs aren't critical enough, just hold off on a release until you have more fixes/features.

Answer (score 2):

jbowes is right, there's no way to do it.

I disagree with him though, in that I think users generally aren't annoyed by frequent updates, especially if they fix things, as long as you're not upping a new version every day for three weeks.

If you're really worried about it, just add some little UI improvement that people will like. You're fine!